# Linux software to track historical computational resource usage

Tags: linux, monitoring

Can anyone provide advice on an opensource app/software to track and store historical computer resource usage (eg. tracking average monthly CPU, GPU, RAM, and storage "usage" (quotes because this may be measured in some multiple different ways for each components))?

The idea of this would be for being able to have a better understanding of my baseline requirements the next time I need to buy a computer. Eg. I would be able to say "oh, over the recent years I averaged about 500GB of disk space utilized per month, used at most about 12GB of RAM, averaging at about 6GB at any given time. So if available, I should try to get a computer with at the very least 6GB RAM and 500 disk space."

Comment: I'm using *Monitorix* for that, see [my 4 answers recommending it](/search?q=monitorix+user%3Ame) for details. Though it probably wouldn't deal with "500 disks" (that should probably be "500GB" I guess ;)

Comment: Classically, you'd install the `sysstat` package and then install and configure `sar` - the system activity reporter. I personally use `munin`, because some older ubuntu release had it preinstalled.

Comment: Have you looked at https://collectd.org/?